# How to merge channels via export & import?

Tags: export, import

I am doing a large site overhaul which includes needing to merge some channels with quite a lot of posts. I have Importer and DataGrab for reimporting the data, but I am not sure how to export such a large number of posts as it seems likely doing it via templates will be difficult.

I attempted to use the Zeal Smart Export module to create a .csv export of the channel I wanted to merge into another (also tried the .xml export). However, it appears that it produces an export where all tags, etc have been escaped and rendered as character entities, so that when I re-import the data with DataGrab, the posts appear with html tags visible rather than processed.

Comment: Why not just find and replace all `&gt;` and `&lt;` by their respective characters?

Comment: Hello Linda, 
I am developer of zeal smart export. To process a proper xml file, It is important to convert all html tags into character entities, But when it revers back in import process, PHP itself convert it back. Can you please let me know your DataGrab version ?

Comment: I have DataGrab 1.9.2. I'll try again with the xml, to make sure I had it right in the setup.

Comment: Correction. I only tied csv. I never got anywhere with the xml because I can't figure out what DataGrab wants when it asks for the xml path.

Comment: You have to enter root/elements in xml path. Where root is main xml entity and elements are sub entity which repeats.

Comment: Hmm, I have tried various combinations of this -- /root/element, /root/elements, root/element, root/elements, etc, and none seem to work.

Comment: Well, it seems the import issue is with DataGrab, because Importer works. So there I have a solution until I upgrade to EE 3, at least.